# how to pass property from control to drawable in android using xml?

Tags: android

I was looking for how to create rounded buttons and it's simple enough. But I would like to be able to pass the color property to the drawable so that I can pass a different color for various buttons in the app instead of having to create a separate drawable xml for each color. In wpf we could reference the properties passed in using bindings, but I'm not sure what the proper method is in android.

button_rounded.xml

```
     <Button   
         color = "white"
         android:background="@drawable/rounded_button"
                        />

     <Button   
          color = "blue"
          android:background="@drawable/rounded_button"
                        />
```

I want to be able to pass the color from xml to the drawable rounded button so that I can maintain only one xml file. Is this possible in android?

Comment: well, that is not quite what I am looking for. What I really want is a way to set the shape in xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Kotlin:

```
(yourButton.background as ShapeDrawable).paint.color = new_color_value
```

You can also adjust the ShapeDrawable before assigning to for a View.

```
val drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context,R.drawable.your_shape) as ShapeDrawable
drawable.paint.color = your_another_color
```

Another way is using `backgroundTint`:

```
  <Button
      android: backgroundTint = "your_new_color"
      android: background = "@drawable/your_shape"
   />
```

Comment: I see. so it's not possible to pass these variables through xml alone then?

Comment: @JamesJoshuaStreet I modified my answer a little bit.

Comment: thank you sorry for the noob questions. I've done this sort of stuff in windows before but haven't had to do android gui till yesterday. anyway not sure how good my xml code is, but the result looks very nice at least